# vuejs include javascript library in spa

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

i'am creating spa application using vuejs and i find out that i have 3 option in loading my javascript library like bootstrap.js or jquery.js and other javascript library:

**1.
first** is by include all javascript library that i will use in my application in index.html where my vuejs application will live but i find that there is some javascript library that not working to well

**ex:** there is some javascript library that calculate page height by selecting some div with specific id="page-container", but that div not loaded when page is rendered from server, so at that moment the javascript will throw error since id="page-container" not exist yet.

**2.
second** is by adding it like this to all my javascript library js

```
// before you use your files in some components,you should package them
// your local files
export default {   //export your file
   your_function(){ // defined your function
   ...
   }
}

// now your can use it
// your component file

<script>
import local_file from 'your_file_relative_path'
//now you can use it in the hook function
created(){  //or other hook function
   local_file.your_function() //call your function
}

</script>
```

but that mean i need to change every javascript library that i use...

**3.
third** is by adding it using npm, and just in the vue component import it, it works okay and feels more natural but not all my javascript library are in npm, some of them is admin template related that i bought from themeforest and will never be in npm.

---

so which one is a better way or maybe there is much more better way that those 3 option that i find out? its hard to find any tutorial or discussion that mention adding other javascript library to spa vuejs most of them just put a bootstrap into index.html and done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If your library exist in NPM, then this is the best option, because then you have this option to import only the part of the script that you need for certain components, for example, fontawesome library, you can import only the icons that you need instead of import all of them!

but if your script is not in NPM, the best option is to run your script in `beforeMount` or `beforeCreate` of the component that the script needed to run.

the third way which is add the link reference on html is not really suggested, since it will be global and will reduce the performance.

Comment: so for my condition it is more better to use second option? but is it a more better way than what i provided up there? since it will mean i will change my javascript library file one by one by adding export default function to each library....

Comment: you should see what are your requirements, I mean u need to see  how many of you components are going to use the library?  if it's only for few of them it will be the best, but if you are going to use it for all or most of your components then make it global.